# Yarn install with multiple git dependencies results in "EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir ..." error

Tags: node.js, windows, yarnpkg

Node (v14.2.0), Yarn (1.22.4), Windows 10

Context: I have several node projects hosted in a private git repo. I have several cross dependencies between projects, e.g. project C depends on projects A and B, and project D may depend on C and A (perhaps this is my problem?). I generally have my package.json files set up to use the git repos directly, and it works reasonably well for the projects with one or two dependencies.

One of my larger projects has many dependencies on my other projects. Running yarn install on this project gives me this error consistently:

`EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir [some C:\\...Yarn\\Cache\\... directory]`

The install ends with that error, and node_modules not being created.

I worked around the issue by removing all (nine) git dependencies from my package.json and then adding them one-by-one and running `yarn install` each time. No issues, no errors, and in the end I have a fully functioning node project. Great success!

The question here then, is why can I not install (run `yarn install`) everything at once. I have tried the tricks I found googling - clear the yarn cache, use npm install, run npm adduser or npm login, run as administrator... every combination of those actions resulted in the same EINVAL error.

My guess would be that yarn is trying to do "too many things at once" and its resulting in filesystem errors (trying to mkdir a dir that is locked)... but why is this not documented, and more importantly, why is there not a way to tell yarn to install "one thing at a time"? If there is, and I missed it, I would love to know about it.

Cheers!